# Java object reference outside loop

Tags: java, coding-style

Why in java its a best practice to create the object reference before the loop.

```
List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();
    Object ref= null;
    for(Object obj: objects){
         ref = new Object();
         ref.setX(obj.getY());
         objs.add(ref);
    }
```

What is the difference the below code makes

```
 for(Object obj: objects){
        Object  ref = new Object();
         ref.setX(obj.getY());
         objs.add(ref);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post any document which says its a best practice?

Comment: I don't know about best practice and I don't really know much about memory consumption, but I would imagine creating 1 object and "resetting" it over and over is cheaper than creating lots of objects. But again, I just imagine that. Anyone know?

Comment: @HypnicJerk The object gets created every time new Object() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is a must if you want to use the reference outside of the loop because of the scope of the variable.

If you define the variabl inside the loop, it's scope is limited to the loop.

If you define the variable outside the loop, you can use it after the loop has finished.

Comment: Yeah but isn't it a good idea to minimise the scope of local variable? http://thefinestartist.com/effective-java/45

Comment: Yes to the mínimum you need

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between examples you have provided.